# Display times in 24hr... can I just show the hour if it's not 30 minutes past?

Tags: php, xml, strtotime

Is there a way to only show the hours of a time if it's not 30 minutes past, but show :30 for when the time is 30 minutes past?

http://new.clairvoyant.co/details/?Pin=4378 This is my page. In the schedule you can see when the blocks are really short, it's a real struggle to display the time period within them.

What'd I'd like to do is to show a format like 12pm - 4pm if the start and end time are just hours. And show 12pm - 4:30pm if one of them is 30 minutes.

Is this able to done just by formatting strttotime? The input variable is in 24hour (24:00:00). The ending output is formatting into 12 hour.

```
$Start12 = strtotime($Shift['Start']);
$Stop12 = strtotime($Shift['Stop']);
```

And is outputted like:

```
<span class='c'>".date('g:ia',$Start12)." to ".date('g:ia',$Stop12)."</span>
```

Comment: Will the date **always** be on the hour or half-hour?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you also might want to remove the redundant 'am' or 'pm' if both periods have the same meridian. Shorten "8am-11am" to "8-11am"; "2pm-4:30pm" to "2-4:30pm"; and "11am-1pm" stays "11am-1pm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the **only** number of minutes will be `30`:

```
function printDate30($date){
    if(date('i',$date) == 30){
        return date('g:ia',$date);
    }else{
        return date('ga',$date);
    }
}
```

and use

```
echo "<span class='c'>".printDate30($Start12)." to ".printDate30($Stop12)."</span>";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/c2AhcELC

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm just wondering now, is it possible to incorporate Tenner's idea above?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example mate, I've not syntax checked this though:

```
    // Create a new object from your start time
    $firstDateTime = new DateTime( strtotime( $Shift['Start'] ) );
    $firstDateTimeFormatter = 'H'; // Set the object to be default formatted for the hour only

    // Repeat, blah...
    $secondDateTime = new DateTime( strtotime( $Shift['Stop'] ) );
    $secondDateTimeFormatter = 'H';

    // If the minutes for this object are not 00 then we want to format the time
    // differently, these two checks do that
    if( $firstDateTime->format('i') != '00' )
        $firstDateTimeFormatter = 'H:m';

    if( $secondDateTime->format('i') != '00' )
        $secondDateTimeFormatter = 'H:m';

    // See the results
    echo $firstDateTime->format( $firstDateTimeFormatter );
    echo $secondDateTime->format( $secondDateTimeFormatter );


    // Put this into a convenient function to use
    function formatTime( $time )
    {
        $dt = new DateTime( strtotime( $time ) );
        return ( $dt->format('i') != '00' ? $dt->format('H:i') : $dt->format('H') );
    }
```